# how to call email application in android platform

Tags: android

there is an intent for “`send an email.`” In our application
needs to send mail, how can invoke that intent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't send an email directly without using a hacked version of the javamail apis, but you can easily have the user send one for you using Intent.ACTION_SEND and an Intent Chooser.

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
emailIntent.setType("text/plain"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"webmaster@website.com"}); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "my subject"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body text"); 
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Make sure you're on an actual device when you test this code as it won't work from within the emulator.

Comment: Note that there's a typo -- it's text/plain, not plain/text. The typo came from the AndroidSnippets.org snippet that I've used in various blog posts and SO answers.