# Launching email application with non-editable email address in Android

Tags: android, email

Currently I have some kind of contact form in my Android application.

I am using an intent similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801687/how-to-call-email-application-in-android-platform) to launch the Android email client.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "contact@mycompany.com" });
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "[Contact us]");
```

The problem is that in the Android email app, the recipient email address (contact@mycompany.com) is editable,  which is inappropriate in this case. So I need some way to prevent the user from changing or adding another email address.

Is it possible to put some extras in my intent in order to give clues to the email client that the recipient email address should not be editable (fixed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's possible. Instead you can try sending an email directly from your app. Have a look at these implementations: [1](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/82d69e1f80cbea9888ab12b375b13069e2a4a712/gerrit-server/src/main/java/com/google/gerrit/server/mail/SmtpEmailSender.java)

```
// Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
// http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.
package com.google.gerrit.server.mail;
import com.google.gerrit.common.Version;
import com.google.gerrit.common.errors.EmailException;
import com.google.gerrit.server.config.ConfigUtil;
import com.google.gerrit.server.config.GerritServerConfig;
import com.google.gerrit.server.util.TimeUtil;
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
import org.apache.commons.net.smtp.AuthSMTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.smtp.SMTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.smtp.SMTPReply;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
/** Sends email via a nearby SMTP server. */
@Singleton
public class SmtpEmailSender implements EmailSender {
  public static class Module extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(EmailSender.class).to(SmtpEmailSender.class);
    }
  }
  public static enum Encryption {
    NONE, SSL, TLS
  }
  private final boolean enabled;
  private String smtpHost;
  private int smtpPort;
  private String smtpUser;
  private String smtpPass;
  private Encryption smtpEncryption;
  private boolean sslVerify;
  private Set<String> allowrcpt;
  private String importance;
  private int expiryDays;
  @Inject
  SmtpEmailSender(@GerritServerConfig final Config cfg) {
    enabled = cfg.getBoolean("sendemail", null, "enable", true);
    smtpHost = cfg.getString("sendemail", null, "smtpserver");
    if (smtpHost == null) {
      smtpHost = "127.0.0.1";
    }
    smtpEncryption =
        ConfigUtil.getEnum(cfg, "sendemail", null, "smtpencryption",
            Encryption.NONE);
    sslVerify = cfg.getBoolean("sendemail", null, "sslverify", true);
    final int defaultPort;
    switch (smtpEncryption) {
      case SSL:
        defaultPort = 465;
        break;
      case NONE:
      case TLS:
      default:
        defaultPort = 25;
        break;
    }
    smtpPort = cfg.getInt("sendemail", null, "smtpserverport", defaultPort);
    smtpUser = cfg.getString("sendemail", null, "smtpuser");
    smtpPass = cfg.getString("sendemail", null, "smtppass");
    Set<String> rcpt = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String addr : cfg.getStringList("sendemail", null, "allowrcpt")) {
      rcpt.add(addr);
    }
    allowrcpt = Collections.unmodifiableSet(rcpt);
    importance = cfg.getString("sendemail", null, "importance");
    expiryDays = cfg.getInt("sendemail", null, "expiryDays", 0);
  }
  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean canEmail(String address) {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
      return false;
    }
    if (allowrcpt.isEmpty()) {
      return true;
    }
    if (allowrcpt.contains(address)) {
      return true;
    }
    String domain = address.substring(address.lastIndexOf('@') + 1);
    if (allowrcpt.contains(domain) || allowrcpt.contains("@" + domain)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  @Override
  public void send(final Address from, Collection<Address> rcpt,
      final Map<String, EmailHeader> callerHeaders, final String body)
      throws EmailException {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
      throw new EmailException("Sending email is disabled");
    }
    final Map<String, EmailHeader> hdrs =
        new LinkedHashMap<String, EmailHeader>(callerHeaders);
    setMissingHeader(hdrs, "MIME-Version", "1.0");
    setMissingHeader(hdrs, "Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
    setMissingHeader(hdrs, "Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
    setMissingHeader(hdrs, "Content-Disposition", "inline");
    setMissingHeader(hdrs, "User-Agent", "Gerrit/" + Version.getVersion());
    if(importance != null) {
      setMissingHeader(hdrs, "Importance", importance);
    }
    if(expiryDays > 0) {
      Date expiry = new Date(TimeUtil.nowMs() +
        expiryDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L );
      setMissingHeader(hdrs, "Expiry-Date",
        new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").format(expiry));
    }
    StringBuffer rejected = new StringBuffer();
    try {
      final SMTPClient client = open();
      try {
        if (!client.setSender(from.email)) {
          throw new EmailException("Server " + smtpHost
              + " rejected from address " + from.email);
        }
        /* Do not prevent the email from being sent to "good" users simply
         * because some users get rejected.  If not, a single rejected
         * project watcher could prevent email for most actions on a project
         * from being sent to any user!  Instead, queue up the errors, and
         * throw an exception after sending the email to get the rejected
         * error(s) logged.
         */
        for (Address addr : rcpt) {
          if (!client.addRecipient(addr.email)) {
            String error = client.getReplyString();
            rejected.append("Server ").append(smtpHost)
                    .append(" rejected recipient ").append(addr)
                    .append(": ").append(error);
          }
        }
        Writer w = client.sendMessageData();
        if (w == null) {
          /* Include rejected recipient error messages here to not lose that
           * information. That piece of the puzzle is vital if zero recipients
           * are accepted and the server consequently rejects the DATA command.
           */
          throw new EmailException(rejected + "Server " + smtpHost
              + " rejected DATA command: " + client.getReplyString());
        }
        w = new BufferedWriter(w);
        for (Map.Entry<String, EmailHeader> h : hdrs.entrySet()) {
          if (!h.getValue().isEmpty()) {
            w.write(h.getKey());
            w.write(": ");
            h.getValue().write(w);
            w.write("\r\n");
          }
        }
        w.write("\r\n");
        w.write(body);
        w.flush();
        w.close();
        if (!client.completePendingCommand()) {
          throw new EmailException("Server " + smtpHost
              + " rejected message body: " + client.getReplyString());
        }
        client.logout();
        if (rejected.length() > 0) {
          throw new EmailException(rejected.toString());
        }
      } finally {
        client.disconnect();
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new EmailException("Cannot send outgoing email", e);
    }
  }
  private void setMissingHeader(final Map<String, EmailHeader> hdrs,
      final String name, final String value) {
    if (!hdrs.containsKey(name) || hdrs.get(name).isEmpty()) {
      hdrs.put(name, new EmailHeader.String(value));
    }
  }
  private SMTPClient open() throws EmailException {
    final AuthSMTPClient client = new AuthSMTPClient("UTF-8");
    if (smtpEncryption == Encryption.SSL) {
      client.enableSSL(sslVerify);
    }
    try {
      client.connect(smtpHost, smtpPort);
      if (!SMTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(client.getReplyCode())) {
        throw new EmailException("SMTP server rejected connection");
      }
      if (!client.login()) {
        String e = client.getReplyString();
        throw new EmailException(
            "SMTP server rejected HELO/EHLO greeting: " + e);
      }
      if (smtpEncryption == Encryption.TLS) {
        if (!client.startTLS(smtpHost, smtpPort, sslVerify)) {
          throw new EmailException("SMTP server does not support TLS");
        }
        if (!client.login()) {
          String e = client.getReplyString();
          throw new EmailException("SMTP server rejected login: " + e);
        }
      }
      if (smtpUser != null && !client.auth(smtpUser, smtpPass)) {
        String e = client.getReplyString();
        throw new EmailException("SMTP server rejected auth: " + e);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      if (client.isConnected()) {
        try {
          client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
        }
      }
      throw new EmailException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (EmailException e) {
      if (client.isConnected()) {
        try {
          client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
        }
      }
      throw e;
    }
    return client;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately 1st link is not found.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question but you can use intent like this....

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,BirdsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Status","fixed");
        startActivity(intent);




Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        int status = b.getString("Status");


 //do whatever you want with status...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you. you have tom write this proprty in your EditText

```
EditText.getFreezesText()
```